# Is there a name for the generalization of the concept "Abelian group" where the axiom $-x+x = 0$ is weakened to the following?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, abelian-groups, inverse-semigroups

Is there a name for the generalization of the concept "Abelian group" where the axiom $−x+x=0$ is replaced by the following list?

1. $−0=0$
2. $−(x+y)=−x+−y$
3. $−(−x)=x$
4. $x+(-x)+x = x$

In multiplicative notation; we replace the axiom $x^{-1}x=1$ with the following list:

1. $1^{-1}=1$
2. $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$
3. $(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$
4. $xx^{-1}x = x$

*Examples.*

- Any Abelian group satisfies the above axioms in their additive form.
- The multiplicative structure of any **zero-totalized** field satisfies the above axioms in their multiplicative form, but does not satisfy $x^{-1}x=1$, since $0^{-1} \cdot 0 = 0 \cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: Concerning your notion of a "zero-totalized field": If $0^{-1} = 0$ in any field, then $00 = 1$. But this contradicts the basic property $a0 = 0a = 0$ which holds in any ring.

Comment: Another example is square matrices with transpose as "$-$".

Comment: @Svinepels, no; the reciprocation axiom in the language of fields is $\forall x(x \neq 0 \rightarrow xx^{-1}=1),$ and not $\forall x(xx^{-1}=1)$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, do they really satisfy axiom 4? I don't think this is correct, since not every matrix is [skew-symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix).

Comment: Woops, I didn't see that addition.

Comment: @user18921: Ok, so if I understand correctly, $0^{-1} = 0$ doesn't imply $00 = 1$?

Comment: @Svinepels yes, all we can deduce is that $0 \neq 0 \rightarrow 00^{-1}=1$, which is vacuous.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yep I stuffed up the first draft, not your fault.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, because the axiom $xx^{-1}x=x$ is equivalent to $xx^{-1}x = x1,$ so this basically says that in the presence of $x$, the expression $x^{-1}x$ behaves as expected. This is a familiar idea from linear algebra; see also [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).

Comment: Following the link you gave me, it looks like this is just a commutative regular semigroup with identity on which you've chosen a pseudo-inverse for each element.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, hmm perhaps. Axiom 1 certainly follow from 4; if we can show that both 2 and 3 follow, then you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it's called a (commutative) *inverse monoid*. For further details, see Wikipedia<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#In_a_semigroup), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Properties)</sup> or Lawson's *Inverse Semigroups*<sup>[4](http://books.google.com/books?id=2805q4tFiCkC&pg=PA20)</sup>.

(I haven't proven that the sets of axioms are equivalent. You may want to reserve the bounty for someone who does so.)